# Wordpress. Множественное дублирование страниц, но редактирование одной

Tags: wordpress

Есть одна страница с основным контентом. Нужно сделать N дублей этой страницы и в каждой менять только одно слово и сам url. Но редактирование главного контента должно происходить на одной странице, а применяться везде.

Это что-то в духе переопределение шаблона любой записи, только не со стороны кода, а в админке.

Ещё подробнее. Есть страница Услуга 1. Делается 10 дублей (у каждой своё название и url). На странице Услуга 1 поменялись изображения и все 10 дублей автоматически эти изменения подтянули.

Подскажите хотя бы направление, куда смотреть, а то в гугле только плагины дублей страниц обычные.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите хотя бы направление, куда смотреть, а то в гугле только плагины дублей страниц обычные.

Вообще создание отдельных страниц для такой задачи - не самый красивый метод. Но если очень хочется, то например можно общий контент поместить в шорткоды.
Править соответственно шорткод.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея, попробую. А есть какой-то другой метод?

Comment: @РомаХр чем шорткоды-то не нравятся?

Comment: @РомаХр, есть разные методы. Но шорткоды - самое простое (в тч и по управлению) и очевидное

Comment: @KAGGDesign ничем, просто поинтересовался, попробую с ними

Comment: @РомаХр а так-то можно придумать 10 вариантов, как это сделать. Но SeVlad прав - проще всего на щорткодах (и указать слово для замены как параметр шорткода :) )